# Calling onResume of one Fragment from another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

is it possible to call the onResume in a Fragment from an activity holding the Fragment. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but there is no reason on earth you should *ever* do such a thing. What is your goal?

Comment: ...particularly considering that `onResume()` of the fragment will already by called by the activity, as part of standard `onResume()` processing, for any fragment being managed by the activity.

Comment: Okay. I have a Volley Json Request in my onResume in one of my fragment, and I have a Button in the FragmentActivity holding it. All I just need to is to reload the Guy anytime the button is pressed.

Comment: You should make another public method in your fragment for reloading your data -- don't hijack `onResume()` for that.

Comment: I don't know why, but the fragments crashes the app 
if I'm not using the onResume

Answer (score 2):

The `onFoo()` methods are lifecycle callbacks. You don't call them, the OS does.

Comment: in activity  we can do it using `(MyActivity)getActivity.onResume();` ??

Comment: @Purushotamrawat No, you should never do that. Instead, follow the answer given by peacepassion.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to put the Volley Json Request logic in another method and call it in onResume(). So you can do the request anywhere other than inside onResume().